# Colouring by derived continuous variable in ggplot2 box or barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, statistics, boxplot

I would like to colour the boxes in my boxplot using a palette scale for a continuous variable.

Example data:

```
Sample <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I')
Counts <- c(8, 10, 7, 15, 19, 16, 11, 13, 14)
Group <- c('Group1', 'Group1', 'Group1', 'Group2', 'Group2', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group3', 'Group3')
Factor <- c('positive', 'positive', 'negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'negative', 'positive', 'negative', 'negative')
df = data.frame(Sample, Counts, Group, Factor)
df
bxplt <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Group, y=Counts)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
bxplt
```

That produces a boxplot like this
[image: Example Boxplot]

I want to include a representation of the 'Factor' variable in the same plot. Due to the complexity of my real data, I want to simplify the message by colouring the boxes of the boxplot using a colour scale that reflects the ratio of positive:negative in the 'Factor' column. I derive the ratios using dplyr like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Factor , Group) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(
    pos_Percent = paste0((n[Factor == "positive"] / sum(n)) * 100 , "%")    , 
    neg_Percent = paste0((n[Factor == "negative"] / sum(n) * 100) , "%")   
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Group  pos_Percent       neg_Percent      
  <fct>  <chr>             <chr>            
1 Group1 66.6666666666667% 33.3333333333333%
2 Group2 %                 100%             
3 Group3 33.3333333333333% 66.6666666666667%
```

I want the boxes of the boxplot to be coloured based on the 'pos_Percent' values, i.e. 'Group1' would be 67%, Group2 zero and Group3 33%. I want to set a continuous colour palette using those variables, e.g. 'Blues' from Rcolorbrewer, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

UPDATE
The solution that worked for me (from iod)-

```
summary<-df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(
    pos_Percent = sum(Factor == "positive") / n(), 
    neg_Percent = sum(Factor == "negative") / n())   
newdf<-left_join(df, summary)
ggplot(newdf, aes(x=Group, y=Counts)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=pos_Percent))
```

Comment: If you remove the `paste` that turns those numeric values into strings, you can pass that numeric variable to an aesthetic such as color. A continuous variable will default to a continuous color scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, come to think of it, there's a simpler way, since there's no reason to go through summarize (as noted by Camille in the comment above):

```
df<- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(pos_Percent=sum(Factor == "positive") / n(),
         neg_Percent = sum(Factor == "negative") / n())

ggplot(df, aes(x=Group, y=Counts)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=pos_Percent))
```

Comment: That very nearly gets me what I want, thank you. But with that code ggplot is treating pos_Percent as a categorical variable, and I want a continuous colour scale. This makes more of a difference with my real data!

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you summarized pos_Percent as character! Why would you do that? Updated my solution. Now you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: What you had before worked great - but your edited solution isn't working for me. I get "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'pos_Percent' not found"

Comment: Silly me - I forgot to assign the mutated table to df. Fixed now.